The mc is born into a royal family without the family's magic and is kicked out. A woman who has no family magic like him adopts him
The MC is born into a royal family and is loved by everyone since they think he will get the family magic, but on his birthday where he is supposed to receive his family magic he fails to receive it. Afterwards, the family locks him in the cellar since he wasted their time and efforts. The MC's sibling visits him while he is locked up and looks down on him. He later gets free and is wandering the streets when a mysterious woman shows up and explains to him that he wasn't cursed to have no family magic, but blessed with magic that is free to change. This woman then adopts the MC so she can pass on her findings of how their similar magic works. (the woman does have a family magic but has seemingly forsaken it to pursue magic that could change, but she can't progress any further since she is limited by her family magic)  skip ahead several years  Now the MC is back in town and meets his old family who when they find out it's him they don't understand how he is able to use such powerful magic that he shouldn't have.(said magic is not only his family's magic but also magic he has made himself.)

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it in colour or black-and-white?

There is a manga, not a webcomic that has this plotline - How I can change the world with translation  https://dragontea.ink/novel/the-story-of-how-i-can-change-the-world-with-my-skill-translation-how-i-used-translation-to-become-the-worlds-strongest/

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

@JohnP sorry, but this is not the one. (you did give me another comic to read tho)

@DavidW sorry, I do not remember whether this was black and white. Also, I'm pretty sure I saw it on YouTube about a year and a half ago.(more or less since my memory on stuff like this is terrible)

@LogicDictates sorry, I do not remember whether this was black and white.

what do you mean you saw it on youtube? Is this even a manga or just one of those ChatGPT-generated stories with DifferentAI-generated images that self-publish on yt?

@MateuszL I don't think it was ai generated since the pictures looked like they were from a manga and they didn't fill the entire screen.
